# Yii2 How can append additional paramater when using gridview filter

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I want to append a parameter to the auto generated parameters of `filtermodel` in `GridView`
How do I add additional parameters?

Comment: Which url are you talking about ? . Can you share some code and specify where does this url appear in you code ?

Comment: for exam this is url that generate when we use filter in grid view http://localhost/reserve/hours-list?HourSearch%5Bgender%5D=men  , but i want to append a parametr like "&date=2016/3/15" to endof this url !

Comment: So everytime the filtering actions occur u need to pass additional parameters to your controller action right ?? .

Comment: Is this parameters view specific ?, i mean if these parameters are dynamic like todays date , we dont need to pass it to controler action. But can be directly used in controller

Comment: Thanks So Much ,filterUrl works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'filterUrl' property of GridView

In your GridView

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'filterUrl' => ['YOUR_CONTROLLER_ACTIONID_HERE','date' => date('Y-m-d')],
    'columns' => [   
    ],
]); ?>
```

first parameter to 'filterUrl' is your action id. After that you can give your additional url parameters as key value pair